# Получение значение select (text, value)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть код. Нужно получить значение у option(именно text и value):

```
<form id="myForm">
<?foreach ($q as $value) {
?>
<input placeholder="text">
<select id="select1">
<? foreach ($url as $value1) {?>
    <option value="<?=$value1['seo_url']?>"><?=$value1['name']?>
  </option>
  <? } ?>
 </select>
 <? } ?>
</form>

<button class="save" type="button">Сохранить</button>
```

Получаю значение с помощью Jquery:

```
$('.save').on('click', function(){
 var result = [];

$('#myForm input').each(function () {
  result.push({
    input: $(this).val(), //нормально получаю значение `input`
    select: $('+ select', this).val(), //нормально получаю значение `select`
    select1: $("#select1 option:selected").text() // Получаю либо значение только первого селекта, которое потом дублируется во всех селектах, либо еще что-то непонятное
  })
 })
console.log(result);
});
```

Как мне нормально получить значение `value` и `text` у `select`?

Comment: `Получаю либо значение только первого селекта, которое потом дублируется во всех селектах, либо еще что-то непонятное` - ну ты же выбираешь значение того, что в данный момент выбрано (`option:selected`), а оно только одно и делаешь это в цикле. какое ты поведение ожидал? ........... а что значит `'+ select'` в коде?

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский, а как это можно исправить?

Comment: Если честно, не знаю. Мне подсказали

Comment: `как это можно исправить?` - исправить что? Что ты делаешь в итоге? тебе так необходимы все данные?

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский, да. Нужно чтобы пользователь видел названия, а при клике получать ссылки. В итоге нужно получить подобное.   `(3) [Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
input
:
""
select
:
"glavnaya_stranitsa"
select1
:
"Главная страница"
__proto__
........`

Comment: Я ничего не понял. какие названия, какие ссылки, причем тут `php`  вообще? зачем это всё засовывать в массив? что это даёт?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, на странице есть категории(отображаются в виде кнопок). Администратор может добавлять категории(со своей страницы). Какую категорию добавить он выбирает из выпадающего списка, администратор должен видеть только названия категории. При клике должны получить название категории и ссылку на категорию, после этого занести ссылку и название в таблицу. Потом на странице пользователя брать все категории из этой таблице

Comment: ты в курсе, что на странице должен быть только один объект с уникальным `id`? а у тебя в цикле их несколько отображается? в итоге jquery тихо офигевает и не может понять какой из `$("#select1 ` ему нужно взять? То есть тебе нужно, скорее всего, починить это

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да согласен, это я от безысходности сделал, но вариант явно не рабочий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напомню, что что на странице должен быть только один объект с уникальным `id`, а у тебя в цикле их несколько отображается. В итоге jquery тихо офигевает и не может понять какой из `$("#select1` ему нужно взять. На будущее, если нужно сгруппировать множество элементов по признаку - используй классы.

А выбрать выбранный элемент у текущего элемента в цикле поможет `find('option:selected')`:

```js
var result = [];

$('#myForm input').each(function () { 
  var select = $('+ select', this);
  
  result.push({
    input: $(this).val(),
    select: select.val(),
    selected:  select.find('option:selected').text() 
  })
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">

  <input placeholder="text">
  <select class="select1">
    <option value="yo111" selected>111</option>
    <option value="yo222">222</option>
    <option value="yo333">333</option>
 </select>

<input placeholder="text">
  <select class="select1">
    <option value="yo1">1</option>
    <option value="yo2">2</option>
    <option value="yo3" selected>3</option>
 </select>
 
 <input placeholder="text">
  <select class="select1">
    <option value="yo11">11</option>
    <option value="yo22" selected>22</option>
    <option value="yo33">33</option>
 </select>
</form>

<button class="save" type="button">Сохранить</button>
```

Comment: если не секрет, где можно так же круто научится js?

Comment: @r.mcreal ну это не круто, это низкий уровень. достаточно просто почитать книги и справочники по ЯП и используемым инструментам

Comment: возникла одна проблема. Если зайти на страницу администратора и просто нажимать на кнопку `Сохранить` то значение поля `selected:` будет пустым, а `input:` и 
    `select` содержат значение. А как сделать так чтобы поле `selected:` тоже содержало значение?

Comment: точнее  `select` имеет постое значение, а не `selected:`

Comment: @r.mcreal ставь по умолчанию атрибут `selected` при генерации страницы у нужных значений. тем более это по-любому придется делать, так как обычно если тот же админ поменяет значение через админку, то при генерации страницы оно должно быть уже выбрано, чтоб тыщу раз не искать.

Comment: сделал так, если я правильно понял : `<option selected value="...">....</option>
        <? foreach (...) {`  но не работает(

Comment: @r.mcreal это надо видеть, я так ничего не смогу сказать

Comment: может мне как-то попытаться код скинуть?

Answer (score 1):

да что так в `jq` вдарились вот на `js` аналог

```js
function save(){
  var result =[];
  document.querySelectorAll('#myForm div').forEach( item => { 
    var select = item.querySelector('select');
    var input = item.querySelector('input');

    result.push( {
    select: select.value,
    selectText: select.options[select.selectedIndex].text,
    input: input.value
    });
  });

  console.log(result);
}

document.querySelector('button.save').onclick = save;
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<div>
  <input placeholder="text">
  <select class="select1">
    <option value="yo111" selected>111</option>
    <option value="yo222">222</option>
    <option value="yo333">333</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div>
<input placeholder="text">
  <select class="select1">
    <option value="yo1">1</option>
    <option value="yo2">2</option>
    <option value="yo3" selected>3</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div>
 <input placeholder="text">
  <select class="select1">
    <option value="yo11">11</option>
    <option value="yo22" selected>22</option>
    <option value="yo33">33</option>
 </select>
</div>
</form>

<button class="save" type="button">Сохранить</button>
```

Comment: а как получить у `select` и `value` и `text`? А то у вас только `value` получает, насколько я понял

Comment: @r.mcreal  вот добавил получение `text`